# Error while converting Item from UOM to Base

Tags: acumatica

I am using the following attribute in the DAC to convert the Qty in to Base Qty

```
[PXDBQuantity(typeof(uOM), typeof(baseQty))]
```

I am getting the following error

```
at PX.Objects.IN.PXDBQuantityAttribute.CalcBaseQty(PXCache sender, QtyConversionArgs e)
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowPersisting(Object item, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row, Boolean bypassInterceptor)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)
at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()
at PX.Data.PXSave`1.d__2.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)
```

The UOM and the Base UOM is same and still I am getting the error. What may be the reason for this ?

Comment: Can you add the DAC field definitions for your Quantity field using this attribute, BaseQty, and UOM fields please?

Comment: What is the actual error message? the post just shows the stack trace. One thing you can try to do is move your DAC fields around in your DAC. Put your Inventory item related fields before the UOM and QTY fields, Put UOM before the QTY fields and see if this makes a difference. The error could come from an early validation before all field values are set?